# Remove a portion

Tags: product-page

How can I remove below portions from Product Page ?? I am using Athlete theme.

[image]

Can anyone help me in this regard ??

Comment: Add code to in your question from <reference name="right"> which is write in <catalog_product_view translate="label"> action from catalog.xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to complete disable right side on detail page then you should  add below code in catelog.xml

```
<remove name="right"/>
```

inside

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
```

Another option for you

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

inside

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
```